# Semiconductor conduction band

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

What would happen in an hypothetical situation if we completely fill up the conduction band, will then also it will conduct? 
I know we can't fill that more than half. 
I think it will also not conduct if we completely fill it

Comment: A completely filled band (be it in a metal, semiconductor, or insulator) does not conduct. You need partially filled bands for conduction.

Comment: Please rethink its conduction band , its like a sea , unlikely to valence band

Comment: If the conduction band is completely filled, it is no longer a conduction band. See, e.g., Ashcroft & Mermin chapter 12: "_Conduction is due only to those electrons that are found in partially filled bands_" (italics in the original).

Comment: Why does electron has to go to higher states for conduction , means if valence band is not fully filled it can do the conduction there also

Comment: Precisely how do you propose to fill up the conduction band and have empty valence band states? But, if the valence band is only partially filled, yes, it can conduct. But, a 'filled' conduction band in that case will rapidly lose electrons to the valence band and also become conducting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conduction band cosists of the unfilled states with the lowest energy. Valance band refers to the filled states with the highest energy. If there is no energy gap between these two, the material is a conductor. If there is a gap, we have an insulator or semiconductor.

Now if you take a semiconductor and put more and more electrons in, it depends on whether the band structure has another gap at higher energies. If it does, and you fill it right up to that gap, you have an insulator or semiconductor again. If there are no more band gaps at higher energies, you can put in as many electrons as you want, it will always be a conductor.